# Plot time series and color by column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with the following [structure][1] -

On a high level it is a time series data. I want to plot this time series data and have a unique color for each column. This will enable me to show the transitions better to the viewer. The column names/labels change from one data set to another. That means I need to create colors for the y value based on labels present in each dataset. I am trying to decide how to do this in a scalable manner.

Sample data ->

```
;(1275, 51) PCell Tput Avg (kbps) (Average);(1275, 95) PCell Tput Avg (kbps) (Average);(56640, 125) PCell Tput Avg (kbps) (Average);Time Stamp
0;;;79821.1;2021-04-29 23:01:53.624
1;;;79288.3;2021-04-29 23:01:53.652
2;;;77629.2;2021-04-29 23:01:53.682
3;;;78980.3;2021-04-29 23:01:53.695
4;;;77953.4;2021-04-29 23:01:53.723
5;;;;2021-04-29 23:01:53.748
6;;75558.7;;2021-04-29 23:01:53.751
7;;73955.5;;2021-04-29 23:01:53.780
8;;73689.8;;2021-04-29 23:01:53.808
9;;74819.8;;2021-04-29 23:01:53.839
10;10000;;;2021-04-29 23:01:53.848
11;68499;;;2021-04-29 23:01:53.867


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM2P6.png
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as each dataframe has the datetime column labeled as 'Time Stamp', you should just be able to do this for each one:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = #get def 
df.plot.line(x = 'Time Stamp',grid=True)
plt.show()
```

Example df:

```
>>> df
   A  B  C  D                    Time Stamp
0  6  9  7  8 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
1  7  3  8  6 2018-05-16 18:04:05.267114496
2  4  1  4  0 2018-09-29 12:08:10.534228992
3  1  2  5  8 2019-02-12 06:12:15.801343744
4  6  7  9  3 2019-06-28 00:16:21.068458240
5  8  5  9  9 2019-11-10 18:20:26.335572736
6  3  0  8  2 2020-03-25 12:24:31.602687232
7  8  0  0  9 2020-08-08 06:28:36.869801984
8  0  9  7  8 2020-12-22 00:32:42.136916480
9  7  8  9  2 2021-05-06 18:36:47.404030976
```

Resulting plot:

[image]